# Is it possible to revert a hunk in diff-mode?

Tags: diff-mode

With viewing a diff for a modified working copy, is there a way to revert the hunk under the cursor?

That is, reverse the change shown in the diff, making the changes to source-file the diff refers to.

Ideally it would refresh the diff too, although I could handle that myself.

---

Currently I'm navigating to the hunk using `diff-goto-source`, then using `git-gutter:revert-hunk` from the `git-gutter` package, however I would like to perform this inside the diff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd> (`diff-apply-hunk`) on a hunk which has *already* been applied, diff-mode will detect this and ask whether you wish to reverse that change.

You can also request this directly by passing a prefix argument to the command.

In cases where the context is insufficient to tell whether or not the patch has been applied, the latter method would be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, found there is an argument to reverse `(diff-apply-hunk t)`, _(this could be used to update the answer)_

Answer (score 5):

There are `R` in `diff-mode`.

> `R` runs the command `diff-reverse-direction`
>
> Reverse the direction of the diffs.

So first `R` and then `C-c C-a` to apply reversed diff.

It is possible to revert individual hunk without reversing whole diff by invoking `diff-aply-hunk` with prefix argument. So another solution is `C-u C-c C-a`.

Comment: While this is good to know, I'd like to be able to remove the hunk in a single step (view-diff, navigate to hunk, revert it).

Comment: TIL `C-u C-c C-a`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding own answer, since `diff-apply-hunk` didn't do exactly what I wanted.

This is a stripped down `diff-apply-hunk` with some modified behavior, to revert hunks without changing the context.

- The buffer is saved after reverting.
- The hunk is removed.
- No new windows open.

It allows for quickly navigating over a diff and reverting hunks, without having to switch buffers and save each time.

```lisp
(defun diff-apply-hunk-reverse-and-save (&optional _arg)
  "Revert the current hunk, removing it from the diff, saving the buffer immediately."
  (interactive "P")
  (diff-beginning-of-hunk t)
  (pcase-let
    (
      (`(,buf ,line-offset ,pos ,_old ,new ,switched)
        (diff-find-source-location nil t))) ;; last arg is 't for always reversed.
    (cond
      ((null line-offset)
        (error "Can't find the text to patch"))
      (switched
        (error "Patch is already removed"))
      (t ;; Apply the hunk
        (with-current-buffer buf
          (goto-char (car pos))
          (delete-region (car pos) (cdr pos))
          (insert (car new))
          (save-buffer))
        (diff-hunk-kill)))))
```