# How to know if the buffer returned by a function is newly opened?

Tags: buffers

I'm using a command that reverts a diff chunk in a buffer ([linked question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54474/2418)), however I don't know if the buffer is newly opened - or if an existing buffer is used.

While I could make a list of all buffers, then check if that buffer is in the original list, is there a better way to know if the buffer from a function is newly created or not?

Comment: Yes, I would do what you describe. (`buffer-list` gives you a list of all buffers.)

Answer (score 3):

*"Newly opened"* can only mean relative to a state when the buffer didn't exist. Every time prior to when it came into being it didn't exist.

So yes, you need to take a snapshot of the list of existing buffers at some point prior to creating the new buffer, in order to later check whether the buffer is "new" - compared to that prior snapshot moment.

Save the value of `buffer-list` in a variable (e.g. `let`-bound), and then, later, check whether the buffer in question is in that previous snapshot. If it is, then it's not new; if it isn't, then it's new.

---

If you're only interested in certain kinds of buffers then you can filter `buffer-list`, to make your lookup quicker.